# KVO on adding/removing objects through NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller

How can I get a notification when an object has been added/removed through an `NSArrayController` ?

I tried something like

```
    [core addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:0 context:nil];
```

I do get a notification of something has been added or remove but I don't know which object and I don't know what has been done (removing or adding).

The `change` dictionary of  `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` doesn't return any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I would bind a NSMutableArray to the NSArrayController's contentArray and observe that.

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *array;

[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"array" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

To get the changed index, you can use

```
[(NSIndexSet *)[[change allValues] lastObject] lastIndex];
```